# Universal Windows App in C++/CX

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I tried to create UWP application for Windows 10 in MS VS 2015 up3 C++/CX. If I launch it in Visual Studio
using "Start with/without debugging" my application is running ok. But if I close VisualStudio and
try to launch my application i.e. file App1.exe in Release directory I will obtain an Error Access Denied.
WHY ? how can I launch my UWP application on my computer ?

Comment: You launch UWP apps from the Start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP apps work in SandBox these apps can only run in context of an app container,( administrator mode don't affect) find your app in **Start  Menu-> All apps**  and click on Icon